# Where do I get information about the support for 12 Bit color depth on the web?

Tags: css, colors, photo, color-depth, srgb

I want to know, when **12 Bit** colors will be supported by the w3specs.

Currently webcolors are defined **8 Bit** as **sRGB** (like: #FFFFFF or rgba(255,0,0,100) )

So I wonder, if there ever will be something like ** 12-Bit sRGB** where you define colors like:

- X#**FFF** FFF FFF - instead of #**FF** FF FF
- Xrgba(**255*16**,0,0,100) - instead of  rgba(**255**,0,0,100)

Supporting just 10 Bit (what is actually just needed by uppcoming displays), would be quite impossible cause of the poor 8+2 Bit format, so the color white would be #8FF, which is quite ugly.

I have already tried to find this information in a w3Spec, but I wasn't lucky.

Maybe someone can show me a **link to the proper w3Spec**, or Working Group

---

Why i need this?

- I want to enable the canvas element to support 10Bit/12Bit colors, this would be nice for several webapps like photo editing and 3D-games, it also would be nice just for websites, to use 12 Bit in PNG files, or virtually seemless color transitions.

Comment: The terms you are looking for are 36-/48- bit colours or "deep color". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#Deep_color_.2830.2F36.2F48-bit.29 There doesn't seem to be any specs, though... although much of this will be down to browsers and the way they render images.

Comment: ok, so there aren't already any specs by w3 out there... your link helped me to realize that sRGB is already capable of deep color, but currently most software is designed to use it with 8-Bit

Comment: Yeah, this is likely to be a big thing to change on many levels. (I don't think any notation currently available to CSS supports values with more than 8 bits per colour though.)  I'm not an expert in this but this looks like the current state of the art: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#colorunits

Comment: thx, this w3 link is actually what I was looking for. I will try to find some additional information in the working group archiv, and maybe propose something like 12-Bit support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked up the w3specs and the css mailing list, and you already can use 10 Bit colors, by writing somthing like:

rgb(0.1%,0.1%,0.1%) the browser will then decide, if it will round down to 0%

> CSS Color Level 4 will also extend rgb() and rgba() to accept a 
>   <number>, where an <integer> was used, so that you can write:
>
> rgb(0.25, 0.25, 0.25), which may or may not be rounded to rgb(0, 0, 0)
>
> -- Simon Sapin, on [CSS-color Mailing List](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Dec/0167.html)

For further information read [CSS-Color Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#changes-from-3) -  Editor’s Draft, 7 October 2013